# Implementing Knowledge in Salesforce Communities

Tags: community, knowledge, articles

I have a Salesforce Developer Edition Account. I have set up Knowledge(Articles) and a simple Community which implements Cases. The knowledge tab, even after adding it in the Community Tabs section does not show up in a live Community. Why is this so?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue. You need to grant at least READ access on one of the Article Types for your Community users.

I had trouble finding it under the new style of the Profile look/feel, but reverting to the old style Profile they show up under the Object CRUD settings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Setting up Knowledge is extremely complicated. Please do a Google search for Knowledge Setup (https://www.google.com/search?q=knowledge+setup+salesforce) and see the first entry. Follow the instructions and read all the documentation, then come back here with any specific questions.